# Parcel and rc-table breaks on production build

Tags: reactjs, antd, parceljs

I have created a sample react app from [createapp.dev](https://createapp.dev/) and added [antd](https://ant.design/) in the `package.json`.

I have been playing around with the [table](https://ant.design/components/table) component from `antd`, and all worked fine when running locally. My snippet looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Table} from "antd";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div>Table</div>
        <Table dataSource={[]} columns={[]} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And the `package.json` is this:

```
{
"name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm dist/bundle.js",
    "start": "parcel src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.8.2",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1"
  }
}
```

Then after running `yarn build` command it successfully generates the build, but when serving the production build, it breaks with errors like `TypeError: s is not a function` which comes from `Header` component of `rc-table`.

I've searched for a workaround and but wasn't able to find a solution. Does that mean we can't use `Table` component from `antd` and why is this issue not detected when running the production build? Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

**Edit**: Found an [online demo](https://tommos0.github.io/parcel-typescript-antd/dist/) with a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

**The Parcel Bundler (`1.x.x`) does not support multiple JS files having the same content.**

You can add the following script in `scripts/fix-parcel-rc-table-issue.js`. Then run it before each build (e.g. `"build": "node fix-parcel-rc-table-issue.js && parcel build index.html".` ).

```
const fs = require('fs')

const MARKER = 'CHANGE_CONTENT_HASH'

for (const file of ['BodyContext.js', 'ResizeContext.js', 'TableContext.js']) {
  const filePath = require.resolve(`rc-table/es/context/${file}`)
  const content = fs.readFileSync(filePath).toString()
  if (content.includes(MARKER)) {
    continue
  }
  const newContent =
    content + `\nfunction ${MARKER} () { return ${Math.random()} }`
  fs.writeFileSync(filePath, newContent)
}
```

#### Background

This exact issue has been reported to Ant Design as a bug. They did some digging and found the underlying parcel issue. [Here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/22943#issuecomment-612965205) you can find some details.

The Parcel developers don't want to fix this in `1.x.x`, but are telling users to switch to the (currently) unstable `2.x.x` version. [This issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/3368) has some more details.

The Parcel developers suggest using the `--experimental-scope-hoisting` flag. This breaks my build, so I can't verify that this actually fixes the problem. **I advise against using this flag in production as it's experimental, so it might have unexpected side-effects** (in my opinion Parcels track record generally isn't very good).

Instead I followed [FocusCare's advice](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/22943#issuecomment-614483120) and simply changed the contents of the files to be unique. This is a nasty hack though, but seems to be the best option until Parcel `2.x.x` comes out (or you switch to a more mature bundler).